# Cannot convert project: /path/to/myproject.idea/workspace.xml: Error on line -1: Premature end of file

Tags: django, python-2.7

Cannot convert project: /path/to/myproject.idea/workspace.xml: Error on line -1: Premature end of file

I am not able to figure out what made this to happen.Please help me.thank you.